# Forked repo doesn't add itself to .bin

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

Running `yarn add graphql-typewriter` adds symlink to an executable inside `node_modules/.bin/`.
However, running the same command on a forked version of the same package:

```
yarn add  https://github.com/teambirowsky/graphql-typewriter#0.4.0
```

does not add a symlink in `node_modules/.bin/`.

What do I need to learn today about npm :}

Comment: Try `yarn add graphql-typewriter@0.4.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to publish forked version to npm.
In `package.json`, `prepublish` script (Run BEFORE the package is packed and published, as well as on local `npm install` without any arguments) is compiling the files and `bin` script is adding symlink.